# Android Nexus 5 code to create hidden folder stopped working

Tags: android, sd-card, mkdir

//The code was working fine on Nexus 5 for months but suddenly it stopped working, but //it working fine on all other devices even those with same OS version Kitkat. Below is my //code. Please suggest ASAP.Checked all the permissions in Manifest they are fine.

```
 public static File getPictureStoragePath(int storageLocInt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath().toString()
                + "/.DriverMaticsV/"
                + ActiveJourney.JOURNEY_FOLDER_ID
                + "/Picture/";
        Map<String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage
                .getAllStorageLocations();
        File sdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.SD_CARD);
        File externalSdCard = externalLocations
                .get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);
        Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        //long count = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (sdCard == null) {
            path = null;
        } else {
            path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/.DriverMaticsV/"
                    + ActiveJourney.JOURNEY_FOLDER_ID + "/Picture/";
        }
        if (externalSdCard != null) {
            if (storageLocInt == 0) {
                path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/.DriverMaticsV/"
                        + ActiveJourney.JOURNEY_FOLDER_ID + "/Picture/";
            } else {
                path = externalSdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/.DriverMaticsV/"
                        + ActiveJourney.JOURNEY_FOLDER_ID + "/Picture/";
            }
        }
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? It seems rather trivial to fire up an Eclipse project, copy this code, set a break point, and step through to see where it is not working.

Also, what do you mean by "it stopped working"?  That the function returns null? Throws an exception?

Comment: I checked the folders in my SD card and found it is creating a file but not a directory/folder with the name ".DrivermaticsV"

Comment: If I remove "." it creates all the folders correctly. Please help.